# What was up with the lady in library?

Tags: plot-explanation, it-2017

When Ben was reading the book in library, the lady was in the background (blurred-out) smiling and her face looks creepy.
And when she was in focus, she was normal and just looking for books.

[image: Lady in the background]

Can someone explain what was that?

**Edit:** [Screenshot source Video](https://youtu.be/0iID-OpwZ4E?t=31m21s)

Comment: I suspect this is poor acting by the extra, plus continuity errors.

Comment: ^^ If you saw the movie, it was quite clear that the librarian lady scene was done this way intentionally.

Comment: Look at the frozen ladies right hand. She's wearing the same glove "IT" wears...That's enough evidence for me... :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wanted to jump in to clarify this one.

There's a very strong theme in the book that Pennywise, in his various guises, is not only an evil force himself but also *infects* the town and townsfolk. For example, horrible things happen through Derry's history but people, for whatever reason, are able to look the other way, are able to forget about the events, or in some cases join in on the violence. For example - a slaughter in a bar where the other patrons just keep drinking as if nothing is happening, and in another case, the town congregating on some visiting criminals and executing them in the centre of town.

I read this library scene, much in the same way as the old folks driving past the bullies and Ben right before they cut him up, as an example of this infection. The librarian, in that moment, is leering at Ben as he reads about the death of the kids at the factory. Maybe Pennywise is watching Ben through her eyes and enjoying his discomfort.

Answer (score 0):

Ben was reading a book about Derry's history and while he was turning the pages an image started to appear between the tree branches shown in the book, which later turned out to be Ben's head (not sure). Meanwhile the music score was getting really tense. Everybody else was frozen still except Ben. It all symbolised the fact that It was taking hold of Ben's reality.

One could argue that the librarian lady standing hunched over with a demonic smile on her face was either just a disturbing image adding to eery atmosphere of the moment or she was some kind of manifestation of It in real world.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, i need to clear that *I did not see the movie*

What makes the movie so original is that **It** doesn't want to only scare The Losers. ***It*** wants to scare you too, that's why **It**'s eyes are both turned toward the kid and the camera when we see **It**s head in the sewer at the beggining, that's why there's a scene where you can see a Clown doll move behind the Losers, and that's the deal with the Lady.